# How to convert Counter object dict to string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, collections

Is there a way in Python to convert a Counter dictionary into a string?

I have tried str(counterobj) method but it's unsupported for Counter (from collections library)

Thanks!!

Comment: did you try `help(myCounterDict)`?

Comment: How do you want it to look? Can you provide an example of the required format? Will it be just like the `str` for a regular dict? `str` is supported by `Counter`, but is it not in the format you want?

Comment: What was the problem you had with `str(counterobj)`?

Comment: Hi, my output was way off. It was still outputting the normal Counter[{Key:Value}] instead of normal [Key, Value, Key, Value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
str(dict(Counter([1,3,4,5,6,4,334,4,4,4,3,2,5,4,2])))                                                                                                                                              
# '{1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 6, 5: 2, 6: 1, 334: 1, 2: 2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a string made of frequency of keys, you can

`" ".join(Counter(map(str, [1, 2, 3, 3, 2])).elements())`

and get:

`1 2 2 3 3`